# Generic macros? (as extension of generic functions)

Tags: generics, macros, common-lisp, destructuring

Paul Graham in [On Lisp](http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_19.html#SEC117), Ch 18, presents a number of interesting macros for destructuring various objects, extending the basic tree destructuring offered by `destructuring-bind`. For example, a macro for destructuring the fields of a structure object based on his templates is the following (patterned after the `with-slots` CLOS macro):

```
(defmacro with-structure ((name . fields) struct &body body)
  "Destructuring bind for the fields of a structure object."
  (let ((gs (gensym)))
    `(let ((,gs ,struct))
       (symbol-macrolet ,(mapcar #'(lambda (f)
                                     `(,f (,(mksymbol name f) ,gs)))
                           fields)
         ,@body))))

(defun mksymbol (&rest args)
  "Creates a symbol by concatenating the arguments."
  (values (intern (apply #'mkstring args))))

(defun mkstring (&rest args)
  "Concatenates arguments into a string."
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (dolist (arg args)
      (princ arg stream))))
```

So now:

```
(defstruct person name age)
PERSON
(defparameter p1 (make-person :name "Eli" :age 19))
P1
(with-structure (person- age) p1 (incf age))
20
p1
#S(PERSON :NAME "Eli" :AGE 20)
```

Graham also provides separate macro templates for destructuring a few other objects such as sequences and arrays. My question is about whether it could make sense to add another layer of abstraction, and consolidate these various macros into one call, using a definition something like `(defmacro with-object (pattern (object type) &body body) ...)`. This is akin to writing generic functions, where each object to be destructured would use the appropriate type/class expansion. However, it seems that the macro expansion phase might need to include some incremental compilation in order to determine the object type (unless it was declared by the user). Can compilation be interleaved with expansion to accomplish such "generic" operation; or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Since `defclass` does not define accessors automatically using predictable names, the usefulness of `with-object` is dubious. Note also that `with-slots` usually works with structs as well as CLOS objects. So, how is `with-object` better than `with-slots`?

Comment: https://github.com/m2ym/optima  see LET-MATCH

Comment: @sds Yes, nothing's really added for structs. However, Graham also builds macro templates for destructuring arbitrary sequences, 2D arrays, and sparse arrays. For increased abstraction, it would seem this could be extended to almost any structured lisp object (e.g., complex, pathname, hash-table). I was just curious about macro abstraction possibilities.

Comment: pathnames, ratios and complex numbers are immutable, so usefulness is, again, dubious. however, please feel free to play with this - I am sure you will improve your understanding of macros. just don't expect the result to be useful, usable, or used by anyone, including yourself (I've been there, precious few of my many macros saw any use).

Comment: I get how `optima:match` works, but can someone give an example use of `optima.extra:let-match`? Also, do you prefer optima to trivia?